# How can I parse a javascript string as if entered as text

Tags: javascript, string

When entering a javascript string, some parsing is applied for escape sequences.
E.g., `var foo = "ab\\cd";` will give `foo` a value of `ab\cd`.

I need to take some javascript code as a string, and extract a variable value from it, but when I do so, escape sequences are not applied. How can I reapply text parsing as if entering the string value initially.

Here's an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhaskins/n1f2qgv2/2/). It's simple, so I'll include the code here.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('abc\/def');" oncontextmenu="log(this)">Click or right click</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function log(el){
  var href = el.getAttribute('href');
  var str = href.split("'")[1];
  alert(str);
}
```

Clicking the link will alert `abc/def`, but right clicking will output `abc\/def`.

How can I make right click alert the same as the left click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, if you want to ensure that all string escaping is applied, would be to use eval to perform an assignment of the string value.

```
eval("str = '" + str + "'")
```

or, using newer syntax (template strings)

```
eval(`str = '${str}'`)
```

In case it's unclear, you're building the string

```
str = 'abc\/def'
```

and executing it as code by passing it to `eval`

There is a notable risk to this general approach; because it doesn't seem applicable to your example, I didn't think about calling this out before; but depending on your real use case this could be *very* important:

If the string data *isn't* properly escaped as would be a string literal in code, this could have unexpected results.  If the string originates from an un-trusted source, then those unexpected results could be exploited and you could have a disaster.  Basically if you are taking user-driven input and building an eval string from it, then you need to pre-validate the string for much the same reason you would if building an SQL query in this way.

Of course, in the case of building SQL queries, we have better ways to interpolate user inputs into queries that avoid the issue (and so concatenating user inputs into query strings is generally considered poor practice); but I can't think of a similar tool that would suit this purpose.  So the best I can say is, if you use this technique and inputs might come from an un-trusted source, proceed with caution.

In your example, it would be hard to inject a truly dangerous value, because if you try to inject a `'` the `split` will reject it (and if you try to inject a `"` that would exclude the injection payload from the `href` property, which means even if you happen to use `"` in your eval string template you'd be ok); but even so, one could cause *some* trouble with an HTML snippet like

```
<a href='\'>
```

which would cause you to try to eval the string

```
str = '\'
```

(which has an un-terminated string literal).

If you have reasonable control over the source of the HTML, then maybe it's ok; but it would be good practice to have more deliberate code to sanitize strings used as part of eval statements

Answer (score -1):

try this regex:

```
href = href.replace("\/", "");
```